# Which is the best way to extract matching string from two large arrays?

Tags: php

I have a string "Sony" and Two large arrays ARRAYONE, ARRAYTWO.
I need to find sony  from those two  arrays.

```
My Approach is :
foreach($ARRAYONE as $string1)
{
if('Sony' ==  $string) break;
    matchedElement =  $string1;
} 
foreach($ARRAYTWO as $string2)
{
if('Sony' == $string2) break;
   matchedElement = $string2
}

return matchedElement;
```

is this is the RightWay ?

Comment: Neither. Do you want to use `array_search()`? (And remember to prefix variables with `$`).

Comment: Use `array_search`. [Manual](http://nl3.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php)

Comment: Thanks Wrikken!my bad,i forgot $ ,It was first question on stackoverflow, so little thrilled :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`array_search`](https://www.php.net/array_search) function to do that.